# Can I use the API to post to any course in my domain?

Tags: google-classroom

I am able to create an announcement in my own courses using the [API Guidance page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/create) found here.

I would like to be able to post to ANY course in my domain as a Super Admin.

Is this something I can do with a Google App Script project at all or am I wasting my time looking? Advice and pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

On your super admin account, you could use 2 API methods. You could call `courses.list` [(ref)](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) which will return an array of all the courses. Loop through the returned array.  While looping through the array, create an individual announcement call for each course.

Comment: I can list all the course and get the ids but if I try  ` var response = Classroom.Courses.Announcements.create(optionalArgs, "id here")` I get an error that I don't have permission unless I am a teacher in the course.  I am writing in GAS as in the end I want to take info from a spreadsheet and post it to classes programatically.